# FileUpload ipywidget: how to specify initial directory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using a `FileUpload` ipywidget in Jupyter, and want to specify the starting directory. Right now I have this:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
my_widget = widgets.FileUpload(accept='.json', multiple=False)
```

After googling, and looking at the source code, I am not seeing how to specify the initial directory that will open when the user clicks the widget. On the workstations we use at work, things can be particularly labyrinthine so it will save a lot of time if I can add this as an argument.

I'm open to other simple options than using ipywidgets for exploring directories/loading files within Jupyter, but it does work very well generally.

If it matters, I'm in Windows 10.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the current API, probably part of a security related issue. Other than the file data that gets transfered, no other info is passed back and forth between widget and user.

Comment: @ac24 What I noticed is that after using it once, the next time I use it starts the directory exploration where I loaded the file from previously. If I could figure out how that happened, and just reproduce it...hmm.

Comment: That's probably more to do with information being saved by the browser during a session than the python kernel. Assuming you're using notebook, if you close and reopen your browser does the same behaviour happen?

Comment: @ac24 I finally closed that browser, and cleared cookies, and cleared my browser cache. Even then, it re-opened where I had opened previously.

Comment: @ac24 in terms of security concerns, does this get around them? https://github.com/crahan/ipyfilechooser  Indeed I'm thinking maybe I should be using that. I will test it out and report back, and answer/close if it is sufficient. I found out about it here: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2190

Comment: Opened an issue about this, and one of the developers agreed with you that it cannot be done because it is a wrapper for an html element that doesn't provide this functionality: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3305 . I will explore `ipyfilechooser` which is a different type of widget, and report back when I get time.

Comment: Another option you could do is combine `glob` to list the local files in a pre-determined directory, and a dropdown widget to list them. This would work as long as folks are running the notebook locally, won't work remotely obviously.

Comment: @ac24 good idea if you are sure that is the right directory (which I usually am frankly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to specify the starting directory using the `FileUpload` widget. This was verified by a developer of ipywidgets [in an issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3305) devoted to this topic. Instead, you can use a different custom widget, the `FileChooser` in the [ipyfilechooser](https://github.com/crahan/ipyfilechooser) repo, to do what you want to do.

First, install with `pip install ipyfilechooser`.

Then in your notebook:

```
from ipyfilechooser import FileChooser

starting_directory = 'C:/foo'
chooser = FileChooser(starting_directory)
display(chooser)
```

To see some of the attributes you are most likely to use:

```
print(chooser.selected_filename)
print(chooser.selected)
print(chooser.selected_path)
```

There are many additional options discussed at the repository.

Of course, once you get the path to the filename that you care about (e.g., `C:/foo/foo.json`) then you will have to figure out the best way to open the file using the standard libraries for such things.